# Any analog of rsync for Ant?

Tags: ant, rsync

I need some analog of `rsync` for ant. The issue is to copy files from source directory to the set of subdirectories that was previously accomplished with script

```
rsync -r --ignore-existing $BASE_DIR/common/config/* $BASE_DIR/config
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to call [rsync from Ant](http://www.lightcubesolutions.com/blog/?p=104), you could use the [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task to call [Jarsync](http://jarsync.sourceforge.net/) or [java-sync](https://code.google.com/p/java-rsync/) or you could create a [custom ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) to call either of those libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Zombie question but posting https://gist.github.com/garethr/878364 in case I ever search for it myself again. Pasting Gist content in case something something.

```
<project name="{{ name }}" default="help" basedir=".">
<property name="username" value="{{ username }}"/>
<property name="host" value="{{ host }}"/>
<property name="dir" value="/srv/{{ path }}/"/>

<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY_UK" pattern="yyyyMMddhhmmss" locale="en,UK"/>
</tstamp>

<target name="help" description="show available commands" >
<exec executable="ant" dir="." failonerror="true">
<arg value="-p"/>
</exec>
</target>
<target name="deploy-to" description="show where we are deploying to" >
<echo>${username}@${host}:${dir}</echo>
</target>

<target name="deploy" description="deploy usng rsync" >
<exec executable="rsync" dir="." failonerror="true">
<arg value="-r"/>
<arg value="."/>
<arg value="${username}@${host}:${dir}"/>
<arg value="--exclude-from=rsync.excludes"/>
<arg value="-v"/>
</exec>
</target>

<target name="deploy-test" description="test deploy usng rsync with the dry run flag set" >
<exec executable="rsync" dir="." failonerror="true">
<arg value="-r"/>
<arg value="."/>
<arg value="${username}@${host}:${dir}"/>
<arg value="--exclude-from=rsync.excludes"/>
<arg value="--dry-run"/>
<arg value="-v"/>
</exec>
</target>

<target name="backup" description="backup site" >
<exec executable="scp" dir="." failonerror="true">
<arg value="-r"/>
<arg value="${username}@${host}:${dir}"/>
<arg value="backups/${TODAY_UK}"/>
</exec>
</target>

</project>
```