# Using antBuilder, How can i rename a file that is located on a remote ftp server?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to rename a file located on an ftp server remotely using groovy and antBuilder.
I can send the file and change the name of the file during send using AntBuilder's scp method, but how can I rename a file already located on the ftp server ?

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not possible using antBuilder, which depends on the underlying Ant tasks. The Ant FTP task does not offer this. Better to use rsync. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116363/any-analog-of-rsync-for-ant